# how can i use jquery in twig

Tags: jquery, html, twig

I want to know how to make a function that hides the link `("#id supprimer)` 
and shows it only when I click on `("#Ajouter)`, using jQuery.

This is my twig page:

///////JQUERY////////////

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
                    $(".Ajout").click(function(){
                        $(".Supprimer").tog;
                    });
            });
```

**target links**

```
        {% for produit in p %}
        <tr>


            <td>{{ produit.nomProduit }}</td>
            <td>{{ produit.prix }}</td>
            <td>{{ produit.quantite }}</td>
            <td>{{ produit.description }}</td>

            <td><a href="{{ path('produit_modifier',{'id':produit.idProduit} )}}">modifier</a></td>
  <td><a  href="{{ path('produit_supprimer',{'id':produit.idProduit} )}}" class="Supprimer">supprimer</a>
         <a  href="{{ path('Ajout_Panier', {'id':produit.idProduit}) }}"class="Ajout">add to panier</a> </td>

        </tr>

    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: I changed id to class this is my new code and it still don't work

Comment: i updated my code bro
can you plz help

Comment: Please include the javascript in the question as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to use jQuery in Twig – just put your Javascript code inside `<script>` tags. Nothing special is needed.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    // Store link with class `Supprimer` to a variable
    var $Supprimer = $('.Supprimer');

    // Hide it
    $Supprimer.hide();

    // Show it when the link with class `Ajout` is clicked
    $('.Ajout').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $Supprimer.show(); // You can instead use .toggle() here if you want to
    });
  });
</script>
```

The `e.preventDefault();` means that when you click the link with class `Ajout`, you won't be redirected to wherever the link points to. You can remove that line if you want to.

*Edit:*

You have `$(".Supprimer").tog;` in your code. You probably want this instead:

```
$(".Supprimer").toggle();
```

Comment: i don't get any jquery modification in my twig

Comment: @LouayBaccary You can't modify Twig code with jQuery or Javascript. Twig is compiled into PHP code, which is a server-side language. Javascript is a client-side language, and jQuery is just a Javascript library. See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming